# Error en RStudio con plotweb: Error in colSums(web) : 'x' debe ser numérico

Tags: r, rstudio, r-bipartite

Antes de todo decir que soy un completo novato en el entorno R y RStudio. Estoy trabajando en mi Trabajo Final de Máster. Quisiera graficar una red bipartita pero estoy teniendo muchos problemas. Mi red consiste en una matriz de donantes y receptores. Este es el formato de mi archivo .csv:

```
;PAIS_ORIGEN;AFG;ETH;TZA;PAK;VNM
1;USA;6686.77;1726.46;834.16;2044.88;192.19
2;EU;609.5;396.27;298.63;244.11;84.17
3;IDA;424.68;1637.79;1461.09;1150.64;1939.73
4;FRA;95.65;45.01;26;20.54;341.29
5;JPN;867.2;154.99;182.21;272.97;1622.79
6;DEU;754.42;164.52;207.36;233.14;194.22
7;GBR;524.15;702.51;428.71;483.36;164.92
8;GLF;33.14;371.49;240.98;41.13;23.14
9;ESP;135.02;112.34;23.61;31.12;41.01
10;AUS;201.08;6.87;7.12;152.23;182.97
11;CAN;466.84;210.31;191.81;131.22;57.24
12;IMF;25.07;276.32;324.77;0;0
```

Mi código el siguiente:

```
>setwd("~/Bipartita_PRUEBAS/RStudio_Bipartita")
>library(bipartite)
>mp<-read.csv("matriz_prueba.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
>head(mp)

  X PAIS_ORIGEN     AFG     ETH     TZA     PAK     VNM
1 1         USA 6686.77 1726.46  834.16 2044.88  192.19
2 2          EU  609.50  396.27  298.63  244.11   84.17
3 3         IDA  424.68 1637.79 1461.09 1150.64 1939.73
4 4         FRA   95.65   45.01   26.00   20.54  341.29
5 5         JPN  867.20  154.99  182.21  272.97 1622.79
6 6         DEU  754.42  164.52  207.36  233.14  194.22

>str(mp)

 'data.frame':  12 obs. of  7 variables:
$ X          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ PAIS_ORIGEN: chr  "USA" "EU" "IDA" "FRA" ...
$ AFG        : num  6686.8 609.5 424.7 95.7 867.2 ...
$ ETH        : num  1726 396 1638 45 155 ...
$ TZA        : num  834 299 1461 26 182 ...
$ PAK        : num  2044.9 244.1 1150.6 20.5 273 ...
$ VNM        : num  192.2 84.2 1939.7 341.3 1622.8 ...

>par(xpd=T)
>plotweb(mp)
```

Pero al final recibo el error `Error in colSums(web) : 'x' debe ser numérico`.

Alguien puede iluminarme?

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

Viendo los ejemplos de la ayuda de `bpartite` y de `plotweb()` veo que estaría esperando de entrada una matriz de números o coeficientes cuyo nombre de fila pareciera ser la variable categórica. De hecho, el error es justamente por a existencia de una columna no numérica: `PAIS_ORIGEN`.

Podemos intentar ajustar tu `data.frame` a lo que se estaría esperando:

```
rownames(mp) <- mp$PAIS_ORIGEN
mp <- mp[,3:7]

mp
        AFG     ETH     TZA     PAK     VNM
USA 6686.77 1726.46  834.16 2044.88  192.19
EU   609.50  396.27  298.63  244.11   84.17
IDA  424.68 1637.79 1461.09 1150.64 1939.73
FRA   95.65   45.01   26.00   20.54  341.29
JPN  867.20  154.99  182.21  272.97 1622.79
DEU  754.42  164.52  207.36  233.14  194.22
GBR  524.15  702.51  428.71  483.36  164.92
GLF   33.14  371.49  240.98   41.13   23.14
ESP  135.02  112.34   23.61   31.12   41.01
AUS  201.08    6.87    7.12  152.23  182.97
CAN  466.84  210.31  191.81  131.22   57.24
IMF   25.07  276.32  324.77    0.00    0.00
```

Y ahora aplicando `plotweb(mp)` podemos generar el gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Patricio Moracho! Esto solucionó mi problema! :D